# Changing object visibility after hovering

Tags: css

I want the picture from div to be under the table so that after hover the content shows, the problem is i can't change html all elements should be the same size and be displayed as inline blocks

```css
td {
  display: block!important;
  visibility: hidden
}

.hide:hover:nth-child(n)+table:nth-child(n) tbody tr td.td1 {
  visibility: visible!important
}
.hide{width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-blocks;
}
tbody{width:100px; height:200px; display:inline-blocks;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td1"></td>
      <td class="td1"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="more49042" class="hide" style="background-image:url("https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/image-src.png") !important">
</div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="more5343" class="hide" style="background-image:url("https://assets.crowdsurge.com/datacapture/example/img/example_logo.png") !important">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where are the style definitions for the default values on `.hide`?

Comment: When you post a snippet, at least make sure it works the way you intend to. I only see a blank page.

Comment: @Jhecht it's just an class, because on default this div display attribute is set to none, but i want it visible

Comment: btw i don't know why this snippet doesn't work

Comment: if it is set to `display:none` then your setup here will never work.

Comment: @jhecht but if i set this to block the pictures will land next to the table, but i want the to be underneath

Comment: I'm afraid i do not understand

Comment: @Jhecht ok I get it now. the td can't be displayed in object that doesn't visibly exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I *think* you are trying to do. Please note that I added the `&nbsp;` html entity to ensure that the div shows up. You could probably just set a min-height on the element.

How the CSS works:

Since there will never be a case that I can think of where hovering over something that technically doesn't exist in the DOM is going to work, you want to look for a hover on the table, and then change the visibility of the `.hide` element after it.

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

table:hover+.hide {
  display: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem.</td>
      <td>Quaerat.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="hide" style="background-image:url('//placehold.it/300x300')">&nbsp;</div>
```